# Wrong display of beamer presentation with notes by pdf-presenter-console

Tags: beamer, presentations, notes

I want a double page presentation and want to display it with the pdf-presenter-console. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Test

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Pdf looks fine. When opened with pdf-presenter-console three slides are displayed though.

[image: Screenshot of Pdf opened with pdf-presenter-console]

With a beamer plugged in the output for the beamer display presentation+notes instead of presentation only. How can I handle this? Where is the problem? Is is a LaTeX thing, a problem with the program or with the laptop???

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain what `pdf-presenter-console` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `notes` with the position of the notes ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pdfpc.1.html) for [pdfpc](https://pdfpc.github.io/)):

> ```
> -n, --notes=P
>     Position of notes on the PDF page. Position can be either left, right, top
>     or bottom (Default none)
> ```

So in your case:

```
pdfpc --notes=right filename.pdf
```

If you insert a frame number, the frames will be recognized correctly.
If there is a frame with multiple overlays these will be displayed in small below. In your case frame 2 is recognized as overlay 2 of frame 1.

```
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber
}
```

Comment: Great! But is the code in the tex-file necessary? Seems to work without it...

Comment: Ok. If you don't use any overlays your example works without the LaTeX-code. But if you make one frame with `\pause` and don't use frame numbers it will be interpreted as seperated frame and not as just an overlay of the same frame. If pdfpc still doesn't recognise an overlay you can edit that manualy with some key.